# C++, What and/or where is a pthread executing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

I have built a multi-threaded producer-consumer (add to a Queue, consume off the queue using numerous threads), but I am trying to optimize this further by sending a new produce() directly to the execution threads, if they are idle (instead of enqueue-ing it onto the queue).

So, I need to figure out where a thread is currently executing (is it currently conditionally waiting, or is it executing something). Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the execution thread is idle, won't it be waiting on the queue?  The fastest way to get it some work to do is probably just pushing the work onto the queue.

Do you have reason to believe that the queue is a bottleneck?

Comment: 'If the execution thread is idle, won't it be waiting on the queue?' - not necessarily - I have a cunning plan.. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's what the queue should already do.

First, the thread can't be idle unless the queue is empty, right?

So what does your "enqueue and signal" operation do? It puts a pointer to the data where the thread can find it and then tells the thread to work on the data. That's the minimum task to do what you want to do anyway.

So no optimization should be possible.

Comment: Optimization is possible and does actually provide some performance gain.  I can't remember how much - I used the OP design in a Delphi queue decades ago.  I do remember that it trounced semaphore-based queues, Windows message queues and IOCP queues, (which are painfully slow when used for plain inter-thread comms).

Comment: If optimization is possible, it should be built into the queue design rather than thought of as a separate dispatch path.

Comment: yes, it should be possible to just instantiate such a queue as a descendant of a generic queue - no globals, no external flags.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a global flag for each thread indicating whether it is waiting or not. Just set the flag before going into a `pthread_cont_wait` and reset it when released.

Having said this, I really don't see why you would want to venture away from the classic task queue pattern. It works well in most cases.

Comment: Global flags, apart from the 'global' aspect, don't work unless protected with a lock, whereupon everything gets messy.  Thread state checks and other micro-management like that nearly always go wrong.

Comment: @MartinJames It would be protected by a lock because you can't call `pthread_cond_wait` unless you hold the mutex that protects the shared state. But I agree with both of you that this kind of micro-management is unlikely to be productive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but whether you actually want to is another matter - see the other posts.

First, forget about all the consumer threads waiting on a common semaphore.  To do what you seem to want, waiting consumer threads have to be addressed by instance.  To do this, a consumer that turns up, locks the queue and finds it empty needs to wait on an event of its very own. Also, the consumer needs to provide, in its 'pop' call, the address of where it wants the object put.  So, in addition to the 'normal' object queue, consumer threads that need to wait need a struct containing a pointer and an event to wait on.  You could create an array, or circular buffer, of these wait_structs when you create the P-C queue.

Then you're set.

PRODUCER: (calls push with an object ref/ptr)
Acquires queue lock and checks the list of wait_structs.  If there is an entry, it loads its object into the address pointed to by the wait_struct pointer, (so 'sending a new produce() directly to the execution thread'), and signals the wait_struct event.  If there is no entry in the list of wait_structs, the producer queues its object in the object queue. Oh yes - releases the queue lock :)

CONSUMER: (calls pop with the address where it wants an object ref put)
Acquires queue lock and checks the object queue count.  If it's non-zero, it pops the object, shoves it into the target address it provided, releases the lock and runs on.  If the object queue is empty, the consumer gets a free wait_strut in the list of wait_structs, sets the pointer to the value it passed in, releases the queue lock and waits on the event.  When the event gets signaled, the consumer already has its object, (shoved in by the producer), and can just run on - no need to visit the PC-queue again.

Yes, this design works, (in Delphi, anyway - should work in C++), and is faster than a 'classic' semaphore-based PC-queue, (which is faster than a Windows Message Queue, which is faster than an IOCP queue).

I have got it working with a timeout - I'll let you figure out how to do that.  (Hint - you have to make use of the consumer object location, (that is addressed by the pointer passed in), as temporary storage :)

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but how is it faster?  The secondary code path only runs if the queue is empty.  If the queue is empty, then your workers are sitting idle, and the overall throughput will not meaningfully change by having them "skip the queue" on their next work item.  If your workers are idle, then you need to give them more to do, not make them wait faster.

Comment: It's what you asked for 'sending a new produce() directly to the execution threads, if they are idle (instead of enqueue-ing it onto the queue'. It is faster because of the reduced number of kernel calls compared with a 'classic' PC-queue.  If the queue protection is a futex/criticalSection, no kernel calls are absolutely required in the cases of producers adding objects to the object queue, (ie. no consumers waiting), and consumers taking objects from the queue, (consumer does not need to wait).

Comment: @DerekPark - 'If your workers are idle, then you need to give them more to do' - I can't do that if there is nothing for them to do.  They are idle because there is no work.  If there was work, they would not be idle.  The only further optimizations I could think of require extensive private data for each thread, ie. every thread that wished to use the queue would have to 'log in' first to get their private queue-interface object.  This is too messy for a general P-C queue - it's becoming a threadPool manager.

Comment: I'm not the OP and didn't ask how to send to the workers directly.  My question is how your proposal is actually faster.  I understand that conceptually you might avoid a kernel call with your approach.  But that doesn't matter on the macro scale.  If your workers are sitting idle, then attempting to optimize for the speed of work item transfer will not improve throughput.  And if your workers are not sitting idle, then the queue will have items in it, and your alternate path won't actually run.

Comment: 'I'm not the OP and didn't ask how to send to the workers directly' - mea culpa, sorry.  You're right about the other issues - significant performance gains are only to be expected in those cases where consumers are idle for short periods and latency is important.  In a PC-queue stress test harness with 150 producers and 150 consumers, latency is important for high throughput.  In 99% of all household apps, it's just not that important, which is why I usually use a simple semaphore queue.